# Bruhat cell of a Coxeter element

Tags: algebraic-groups, topological-groups, weyl-group, chevalley-groups

If $G$ is a complex Chevalley group and $H\leq G(\mathbb Z)$ dense in $G(\mathbb C)$, can I find $g\in H$ conjugated in $G(\mathbb Z)$ to an element in the Bruhat cell $BwB$ where $w$ represent a Coxeter element in the Weyl group?

I know that the Bruhat cells that are not the big cell are closed so they are not containing any open sets, but maybe the union of all the conjugation in $G(\mathbb Z)$ of Bruhat-Coxeter cells is Zariski dense in $G(\mathbb C)$?

**Edit**:$H$ is also of finite index.

Comment: "I know that the Bruhat cells that are not the big cell are closed"? Only the small cell (corresponding to $e \in W$) is closed, unless you mean the closed Bruhat cells (in which case, the big cell is the entire variety). The rest are the intersection of a closed set (the closed Bruhat cell) with an open set (the complement of the union of Bruhat cells with smaller $w$ in the Bruhat order). The statement after is still true (they contain no open sets), though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Chevalley group"?      This could be the adjoint-type group, as in Chevalley's 1955 paper, based on the adjoint representation, or could be the more general version treated in Steinberg's 1967-68 Yale lectures, based on a more general faithful representation for groups such as SL$_n(\mathbb{C})$.   In either setting, the group over $\mathbb{Z}$ has a Tits system (BN-pair), with "Weyl group" the full $W$ involved.     This ensures nonrtrivial intersection with each Bruhat cell.

Comment: I meant the more general version by Steinberg, so you are saying that the Tits system of $G(\mathbb Z)$ is the Tits system of $G(\mathbb C)$ intersected with $G(\mathbb Z)$ and have the same presentation for the Weyl group in $G(\mathbb C)$? so $G(\mathbb Z)$ contains nontrivial elements from every cell, but I don't see how it shows $H$ contain a conjugation to an element in a Bruhat-Coexeter cell? Also, I forgot to mention that $H$ has a finite index.

Comment: @JimHumphreys is it also true that for any algebraic extension of $\mathbb Z$, $\overline {\mathbb Z}$, that $G(\overline {\mathbb Z})$ has a Tits system, with the same presentation for the Weyl group in $G(\mathbb C)$? Is there a good source for that?

Comment: @Ami:  I don't have a suitable reference in mind.    But in any case, I don't see why a *Coxeter element* of $W$ should plaly a special role in the Bruhat decomposition here, or why other elements of $W$ should  automatically be involved in a Chevalley group over $\mathbb{Z}$.     (I did study arithmetic groups at an early stage but got more attracted to modular representation theory of algebraic groups.)

Comment: @Ami: By the way, it seems misleading to refer to 'Bruhat-Coxeter cells' here. Coxeter had nothing to do with this idea.  The tag 'topological-groups' is also misleading, since an affine algebraic group (with the Zariski topology) usually fails to be a topological group:  the Zariski topology is typically not Hausdorff.

Comment: @user44191 what about when $G=\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb C)$ and $w$ is the permutation matrix of $(123..n)$ when $B$ is the upper triangular matrices and $T$ the diagonal matrices. Then $J=\{A\in \operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb C)|\operatorname{disc}(A)\neq 0\}$ is Zariski open and contained in $BwB$?

Comment: @Ami For $n \geq 3$, it is not true that $BwB \supset J$. For example, for $n = 3$, the minor gotten by removing the 1st row and 3rd column of any element of $BwB$ is $0$, if I haven't made a mistake, which is not true for every element of $J$.

Comment: @user44191 oops yes you are of course right, I meant that every element of $J(\mathbb Z)$ is conjugate to an element of $BwB$ in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$